# Aligning input-group-addon's via the same width. Can't override CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of inputs in bootstrap that have input-group-addon  tags as labels. On my page, I have labels of various lengths of text, but I want all the labels to be the same width for the visual effect.  I'm trying to manually set the width of these span elements to the largest one I have on the page (for this example, say 75px).

Making my own CSS class doesn't do the trick, bootstrap overrides it somehow that I don't understand.

Making my own .input-group-addon.myClass   CSS class doesn't work either.  The browser shows that this isn't overridden by another style, but I don't see it actually effecting the span element.

Lastly, simply adding a style="width:75px" to the span doesn't work either.

I'm at a loss as to how I can ovveride this style to make all my span's line up regardless of text length.

Code example: http://www.bootply.com/SvJAiwVavY

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your sample code. From Bootstrap, the `.input-group-addon` class has a `display` property set to `table-cell`, so there is no need to do anything other than set an appropriate width. If you set a width that is smaller than the contained text, it's not going to look like it has changed. Try changing your example code to the following:

```
.input-group-addon.test {
   width: 200px !important;
}
```

You may want to change your `text-align` to something other than `center`, but that's up to you.

Comment: But I WANT them inline. That's the whole point of an input-group-addon, to keep the label inline with the input itself.  Changing display to block causes all sorts of problems as exhibited here: http://www.bootply.com/SvJAiwVavY

Comment: Edited. FYI, 75px isn't a very large value, so you weren't seeing results. Most likely, you can do without the `!important` on the width.